# PHP hiding content from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im fairly new to php and mysql and so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a table with the following columns.

```
+----+---------------------+---------------+------+
| id | date                | news_content  | shows|
+----+---------------------+---------------+------+
|  1 | 2013-03-19 14:47:27 | This is news1 |  1   |
|  2 | 2013-03-19 14:47:27 | This is news2 |  1   |
|  3 | 2013-03-19 14:47:37 | This is news3 |  1   |
|  4 | 2013-03-19 14:47:37 | This is news4 |  1   |
+----+---------------------+---------------+------+
```

Show can have the value 0 or 1(default). if the value is 0 I want to hide the news_content and date.

The printnews function prints out all the newsarticles and 3 anchorlinks Show or Hide , Edit and Add.
Do i have to change something in my mysql database so that it doesnt show news when shows=0? 
Or is there another way of doing it with php?

EDIT:
When i press the hide link i want to set the shows value to 0 and hide that article and when i press the show link i want show the article. At the moment i dont have anything that makes the article hide when it has the value 0.

```
function printnews() {
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ")  
    or die(mysql_error());  
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
         $id = $info['id']; 
         $show = $info['shows'];
         if($show == 1) {
           echo "<br><a href=show.php?id=$id&shows=0> Show </a><br>";
         }   
         else if($show == 0) {
           echo "<br><a href=show.php?id=$id&shows=1> Hide </a><br>";
         }
         // Print Articles and Date
         echo "<br><a href=Edit.php?id=$id>Edit</a><a href='addnews.php'> Add </a><br><strong>". $info['date']."</strong><br>". $info['news_content'] . "<hr><br>";
    }
```

Im aware that i shouldnt use the mysql extension so please ignore any comments concerning that.

Comment: Is what you have not working?

Comment: @Explosion Pills The function is being called in home.php and  show.php is empty at the moment. So no its not working

Answer (score 3):

You can update your `SELECT` query to just fetch data where `show` is set to `1`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `news`
WHERE `shows` = 1
```

Comment: The function is being called in home.php and the Show/hide anchor is redirecting me to show.php which is at the moment empty. How would my show.php look like?

Comment: This is what show.php look like <?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$show = $_GET['show'];
$sql = "UPDATE news SET show = '$show' WHERE id = '$id'";
?>

Comment: @Ben Then I think you'd need to be more descriptive about what you want to achieve.